# What's causing my program to stop running? CS50 - Lab 1 - Population Growth

Tags: c, cs50

So I've written the following code, but after asking for the "end value", my program just stops and doesn't continue to the n = n + n/3 - n/4 calculation. Would really appreciate some assistance please. Also, please do not give the code solution to the problem due to CS50's Academic Honesty Policy - just need a nudge in the right direction. Thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int n;
    do
    
    {
        n = get_int("Please enter starting size: \n");
        
    }
    while (n <= 9);
    
    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int m;
    do
    
    {
        m = get_int("Please enter end size: \n");
        
    }
    while (m < n);
    
    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int counter = 0;
    
    do
    
    {
        n = n + n/3 - n/4;
        counter++;
        
    }
    while (n != m);
    
    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", counter);
}
```

Comment: What exact behavior are you seeing and what are you expecting to see? `n = n + n/3 - n/4;` must execute at least once since you're using a `do...while`, and nothing breaks execution before that loop is reached (unless you have UB somewhere).

Comment: The user is supposed to enter a starting size of animals (n) and an ending size (m). The formula (n = n + n/3 - n/4) will then calculate the time it takes to achieve the ending size from the starting size. However, my program just stops running after the user keys in the ending size.

Comment: I don't believe what you're describing is possible, which is why I asked to describe precisely what behavior you're seeing. The more likely scenario is it's getting stuck in a loop; but that would show the program still running; just stuck.

Comment: The only way I can see your program abruptly ending is if `get_int` is killing it.

Comment: I expect you're being asked to stop once `n` is `m` or larger rather than exactly equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know how   `n = get_int("Please enter starting size: \n");`  works but try to change with the normal c function  `printf("Please enter starting size: \n");  scanf("%d",&n);` and same for m

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to add: get_int is a function included with the course's (CS50) #include <cs50.h>

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't "just stop". In fact, depending on input, it may *never* stop.  Did you try with the start 1200 end 1300 example from the spec? Does that work? I expect that it does.

Remember from the spec [*emphasis added*]:

> Your program should then calculate the (integer) number of years required for the population to reach *at least* the size of the end value.

This loop `while (n != m);` will not terminate unless the population reaches *exactly* the size of the end value.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to add math.h library because that will round off your remainder input. I tested this code and it's working. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

int main(void)

{

    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int start_size;
    do
    {
        start_size = get_int("Start Size: ");
    }
    while (start_size < 9);

     // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int end_size;
    do
    {
    end_size = get_int("End Size: ");
    }
    while (end_size < start_size);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int years = 0;
    while (start_size < end_size)
    {
        start_size = start_size + (start_size / 3) -              (start_size 
        / 4);
        years++;
    }

     // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", years);


}
```

Comment: Whare, either in the code you have given or in the OP's, is anything from the `math.h` header file used?